# mysql trigger error before update

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with trigger that I cannot solve. When I made a trigger in Navicat there was no error but when I was updating another database I got an error. The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `status` BEFORE UPDATE ON `db_termine` FOR EACH ROW 
IF (    (NEW.tgebucht >= OLD.tteilnmax) 
    AND (NEW.tgebucht!=0) 
    AND (OLD.tstatus=0)  ) THEN

    SET NEW.tstatus = 1;

ELSEIF (    (NEW.tgebucht < OLD.tteilnmax) 
        AND (OLD.tstatus=1) ) THEN

    SET NEW.tstatus =0;

END IF;
```

And the error is:

Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2:

that is the first SET line. Any help would be appreciated since I am losing my head now with trying to solve it.

Comment: lol @BWS we added code indentation at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because you did not set a delimiter different than `;` making the query end after the first `;` it sees.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `status` BEFORE UPDATE ON `db_termine` FOR EACH ROW 
IF ((NEW.tgebucht >= OLD.tteilnmax) AND (NEW.tgebucht!=0) AND (OLD.tstatus=0)) THEN
    SET NEW.tstatus = 1;
ELSEIF ((NEW.tgebucht < OLD.tteilnmax) AND (OLD.tstatus=1)) THEN
    SET NEW.tstatus =0;
END IF;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f81ec/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `begin/end` statements

```
CREATE TRIGGER `status` BEFORE UPDATE ON `db_termine` FOR EACH ROW 
  Begin
    IF (    (NEW.tgebucht >= OLD.tteilnmax) 
        AND (NEW.tgebucht!=0) 
        AND (OLD.tstatus=0)  ) THEN

        SET NEW.tstatus = 1;

    ELSEIF (    (NEW.tgebucht < OLD.tteilnmax) 
            AND (OLD.tstatus=1) ) THEN

        SET NEW.tstatus =0;

    END IF;
  End;
```